# Get second parent of child item Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, datamodel

I have 3 model.

1. Room - columns: id, name, isactive.
2. Sensor - columns: id, name, isactive.
3. RoomSensors - columns: id, roomid, sensorid, isactive.

I have models for all of them.

**Room**

```
class WarehouseRoom extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tempohub_rooms';

    protected $fillable = ['id','warehouseid','name','isactive','image'];

    public    $timestamps   = false;

    public function warehouse_roomsensors()
    {
        return $this -> hasMany('App\WarehouseRoomSensor','roomid');
    }

    public function warehouse()
    {
        return $this -> belongsTo('App\Warehouse','warehouseid','id');
    }
}
```

**Sensor**

```
class Sensor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tempohub_sensors';

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function roomToSensor() {
        return $this -> hasMany('App\WarehouseRoomSensor', 'sensorid');
    }
}
```

**RoomSensors**

```
class WarehouseRoomSensor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tempohub_roomsensors';

    protected $fillable = [];

    public    $timestamps   = false;

    public function sensor() 
    {
        return $this -> belongsTo('App\Sensor', 'sensorid', 'id');
    }

    public function room()
    {
        return $this -> belongsTo('App\WarehouseRoom','roomid','id');
    }

}
```

The page is not written by me, so I have to continue as it was made. And in blade I have the loop.

`@foreach($warehouse_room -> warehouse_roomsensors -> sortBy('index') as $sensor)`

It must give me the info about sensor on the rooms, but it cant.
So I need to get Warehouse_room -> Warehouse_roomsensor -> Warehouse_sensor

Comment: Why the Sensor hasMany RoomSensors and the RoomSensors belongs to Sensor?

Comment: Are sensors shared between rooms? That seems odd to me... But that being said, you don't define a model for a Pivot Table (`RoomSensors` table is good, drop the `WarehouseRoomSensor` Model); you define a `belongsToMany` relationship between `WarehouseRoom` and `Sensor`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new many-to-many relationship in your room model.

Many-to-many relationships are defined by writing a method that returns the result of the `belongsToMany` method. The `belongsToMany` method is provided by the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` base class that is used by all of your application's Eloquent models. For example, let's define a sensors method on our WarehouseRoom model. The first argument passed to this method is the name of the related model class and the second argument would be the name of the intermediate table.:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class WarehouseRoom extends Model
{
    /**
     * The sensors that belong to the room.
     */
    public function sensors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Sensors::class, 'tempohub_roomsensors');
    }
}
```

Once the relationship is defined, you may access the room's sensors using the `sensors` dynamic relationship property:

```
use App\Models\WarehouseRoom;

$warehouseRoom = WarehouseRoom::find(1);

foreach ($warehouseRoom->sensors as $sensor) {
    //
}
```

In blade

```
@foreach($warehouseRoom->sensors as $sensor)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have made it at last.
Your answer was very helpfull <3